# Constructing a binary tree using queue in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, data-structures

I am trying to write some data structure HW in C++. When I was trying to construct a binary tree using a queue, I was somehow confused by the pointer issues.

```
class Tree{
private:
    struct TreeNode{
    int val;
    TreeNode* left;
    TreeNode* right;

    TreeNode(int x) :val(x), left(NULL), right(NULL) {}
};
public:
    TreeNode* root = NULL;       
    Tree();
    Tree(queue<int>& val);       
    ~Tree();
    string toString_bf();
};


Tree(queue<int> &vals){
    if (vals.empty())
        return;

    root = new TreeNode(vals.front());
    vals.pop();
    queue<TreeNode**> pts;       // what is the meaning of this? Why should use pointers to pointer?

    pts.push(&(root->left));     // also have doubts here, about the reference used in the parameter
    pts.push(&(root->right));
    while (!vals.empty()){
        TreeNode* t = new TreeNode(vals.front());
        *(pts.front()) = t;      // and here
        pts.pop();
        vals.pop();
        pts.push(&(t->left));
        pts.push(&(t->right));
    }
}
```

According to my understanding, left and right are both pointers, why could not just pass values to them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The variable `pts` is a queue of pointers to where subtrees need to be placed later. Those locations are themselves pointers to `TreeNode` (each being either a `left` or `right` data member, of type `TreeNode *`) so it makes sense that you need a `TreeNode **` to point at them.

In other words, each time `*(pts.front()) = t;` is executed, a `left` or `right` member of a previously contructed `TreeNode` is being set to point to the most recently constructed node.

You could make a `typedef TreeNode *TreePtr;` and perhaps it would look cleaner using that.

---

To further clarify what's happening:

Each time the 'while' loop starts:

- `root` is the root of a tree under construction, containing n+1 nodes, each holding one value taken from the input queue `vals` (where n is the number of times the `while` loop has already run)
- `vals` contains all the remaining values yet to be put into the tree (if any)
- `pts` contains a set of pointers to pointers within the nodes in the tree; it contains pointers to all of the pointers which have not yet had subtrees assigned to them; there are n+2 of these.

So each loop makes one new node, makes one of these unassigned pointers point at the new node, and then adds the new node's unassigned pointers to the queue.

Note that when the operation ends, there are always n+2 pointers in `pts`, which are discarded. By knowing how many nodes are needed ( = vals.size()) it's possible to stop doing the `pts.push` operations once enough have been done, which reduces the amount of temporary space needed by about 50%:

```
      vals.pop();
      if( pts.size() < vals.size()) {
           pts.push(&(t->left));
           pts.push(&(t->right))
       } // otherwise we have enough for all remaining vals.
```

Comment: I am just confused about this: could I use **queue<TreeNoode*>** instead of **queue<TreeNode**>** ? Correspondingly, don't use reference  in the following code? @greggo

Comment: If you wanted to put the *value* of `t->left` into a queue, then it would look like that. But the way the code works, `t->left` and `t->right` will always have a value of NULL at the point it's put in the queue, so that's clearly not useful. The point of the queue is to remember the *locations* of pointer variables which need to be set later.

Comment: Or, you could make a struct containing (a) a `TreeNode*` (already constructed node) and (b) an indication of whether it's the left or right pointer in that node which needs to be set; and make a queue of those. But you'd be setting 't' as the (a) part when putting those in the queue, and then the line of code containing `pts.front()` would become an `if` statement with two possible assignments being done. Essentially you are creating a special pointer which selects an existing node and a location within that node. I'm still not sure why you aren't OK with the way the code is now, though.

Comment: Oh, I see. I was trying to copy a null ptr in this case. That is the reason why I need to use its reference. Thank you for your kindly explanation. That helps a lot.@greggo